# Aumentar tamaño Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carrusel

he visto que ya hay preguntas similares o las mismas preguntas a la mía, pero he probado la solución y no funciona. Tengo un carrusel que se puede desplazar arrastrando el ratón, pulsado los botones o mediante los puntitos que aparecen debajo de la imagen. Tengo dos preguntas; la primera es si el carousel va asi de lento, al menos a mi me tarda mucho en cambiar de imagen; y otra es como puedo aumentar el tamaño del carrusel y las imágenes que van dentro, he probado el -inner pero tampoco va.
Aquí os dejo el código, no está todo porque tengo más cosas pero está completo la parte del carrusel.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<title>Vapers de LGS</title>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    
     $('.next').click(function(){
       $('.carousel').carousel('next');
     });
     
     $('.prev').click(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Algunos de los estilos de la página de vapers entre ellos el fondo, los textos, colores, fotos... -->

<style>
body {
 background-image:
  url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/2f/2fq/200/2fqq8a.png?ph=6fd8d12f56");
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: green;
 font-size: 55px;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p {
 color: green;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel img {
    width: 300%;
    max-height: 960px;
}

.carousel-inner {
 height: 800px;
}

</style>

<!-- Aquí va la estructura de la visualización de las fotos de los vapers con sus respectivos nombres y precios -->

<body>

 <h1>LegaGrow Shop</h1>
 <p>Los mejores Vapers de Leganés</p>

 <div class="carousel" data-indicators="true">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper1"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok-vape-pen-22-kit-1650-mah-batera-e-cigarrillo-negro-2ml-tpd-cumple-600x600.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper2"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB1uFURKFYqK1RjSZLeq6zXppXaM/Msn-M50-calor-electr%C3%B3nico-cigarrillo-Vape-Kit-dispositivo-compatibilidad-para-giratoria-de-palo-de-calor-no.jpg_350x350.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper3"><img src="https://www.elementvape.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/j/o/joyetech_ego_aio_all-in-one_starter_kit_-_black_purple.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper4"><img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1B2xKkN6I8KJjy0Fgq6xXzVXai/80-W-Vape-enorme-de-Vapor-cigarrillo-electr-nico-Vaper-E-Cig-Shisha-pluma-Mech-caja.jpg_640x640.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper5"><img src="https://vaporizadoreschile.cl/1458/voopoo-drag-2-kit-vaper-portatil.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper6"><img src="https://cdn.wallapop.com/images/10420/5a/p4/__/c10420p320299011/i730126877.jpg?pictureSize=W640"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper7"><img src="https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/B1154792601/Mlife-M1-Vape-recargable-encierra-Cig-de-e-con-1500mah.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper8"><img src="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g5-M01-61-98-rBVaJFlsUm6Ad7jmAAHp3ge6wj8815.jpg/original-mlife-cigar-vape-pens-kits-de-inicio.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper9"><img src="https://image.dhgate.com/albu_342455841_00-1.0x0/high-quality-huge-vapor-e-pipe-electronic.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper10"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_7247.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper11"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_4405-300x300.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper12"><img src="https://cdn.vapo.es/media/catalog/product/cache/4af76433a19704f5fc51241a28dbbf9d/v/a/vaporesso-switcher-220w-kit.jpg"></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect prev">Anterior</div>
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect next">Siguiente</div>
```

Comment: [Aqui](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) te dejo un enlace hacia una libreria de carousel que te puede resultar facil de usar

Comment: Agradezco la ayuda, me guardo ese código, pero el que tengo hecho está casi terminado y me gustaría acabarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya que no tienes `carousel-inner` la transicion se la tendras que cambiar a los `carousel-item`
El tamaño no se cambia por que materialize pone uno por defecto, para cambiarlo tienes que poner un selector mas especifico o el mismo: `.carousel .carousel-item img`

Para cambiar la velocidad:

```
.carousel-item {
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
```

Para cambiar el tamaño:

```
.carousel .carousel-item img {
    width: 500%;
    max-height: 2060px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<title>Vapers de LGS</title>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    
     $('.next').click(function(){
       $('.carousel').carousel('next');
     });
     
     $('.prev').click(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Algunos de los estilos de la página de vapers entre ellos el fondo, los textos, colores, fotos... -->

<style>
body {
 background-image:
  url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/2f/2fq/200/2fqq8a.png?ph=6fd8d12f56");
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: green;
 font-size: 55px;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p {
 color: green;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: fantasy;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel .carousel-item img {
    width: 500%;
    max-height: 2060px;
}

.carousel-item {
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

</style>

<!-- Aquí va la estructura de la visualización de las fotos de los vapers con sus respectivos nombres y precios -->

<body>

 <h1>LegaGrow Shop</h1>
 <p>Los mejores Vapers de Leganés</p>

 <div class="carousel" data-indicators="true">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper1"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok-vape-pen-22-kit-1650-mah-batera-e-cigarrillo-negro-2ml-tpd-cumple-600x600.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper2"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB1uFURKFYqK1RjSZLeq6zXppXaM/Msn-M50-calor-electr%C3%B3nico-cigarrillo-Vape-Kit-dispositivo-compatibilidad-para-giratoria-de-palo-de-calor-no.jpg_350x350.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper3"><img src="https://www.elementvape.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/j/o/joyetech_ego_aio_all-in-one_starter_kit_-_black_purple.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper4"><img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1B2xKkN6I8KJjy0Fgq6xXzVXai/80-W-Vape-enorme-de-Vapor-cigarrillo-electr-nico-Vaper-E-Cig-Shisha-pluma-Mech-caja.jpg_640x640.jpg"></a> 
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper5"><img src="https://vaporizadoreschile.cl/1458/voopoo-drag-2-kit-vaper-portatil.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper6"><img src="https://cdn.wallapop.com/images/10420/5a/p4/__/c10420p320299011/i730126877.jpg?pictureSize=W640"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper7"><img src="https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/B1154792601/Mlife-M1-Vape-recargable-encierra-Cig-de-e-con-1500mah.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper8"><img src="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g5-M01-61-98-rBVaJFlsUm6Ad7jmAAHp3ge6wj8815.jpg/original-mlife-cigar-vape-pens-kits-de-inicio.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper9"><img src="https://image.dhgate.com/albu_342455841_00-1.0x0/high-quality-huge-vapor-e-pipe-electronic.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper10"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_7247.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper11"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_4405-300x300.jpg"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper12"><img src="https://cdn.vapo.es/media/catalog/product/cache/4af76433a19704f5fc51241a28dbbf9d/v/a/vaporesso-switcher-220w-kit.jpg"></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect prev">Anterior</div>
 <div class="btn green  waves-effect next">Siguiente</div>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, la velocidad ahora es mucho mayor, ya se mueve con soltura, y el tamaño también, esta al que yo quiero, puede que sea solo mi impresión pero lo veo ligeramente a la derecha, pero no pasa nada con esto es mas que suficiente. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Solo te faltaba añadir datos al constructor del carousel. Y junto con la respuesta de [Jovi Parra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/263389/101499) obtienes el tamaño y la velocidad que desees

```
 $('.carousel').carousel({ 
            //Aqui puedes meter las funcionalidades de la libreria
            duration:5
 });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
         $('.carousel').carousel({
            duration:5
          });
        
         $('.next').click(function(){
           $('.carousel').carousel('next');            
         });
         
         $('.prev').click(function(){
          $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
        });
      });
```

```css
    body {
     background-image:
      url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/2f/2fq/200/2fqq8a.png?ph=6fd8d12f56");
     text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
     color: green;
     font-size: 55px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-weight: bold;
    }

    p {
     color: green;
     font-family: fantasy;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 40px;
     font-weight: bold;
    }

    p1 {
     color: white;
     font-family: fantasy;
     font-size: 25px;
    }

    .carousel img {
        width: 300%;
        max-height: 960px;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
     height: 800px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
     
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


    <title>Vapers de LGS</title>
    </head>

    <script>
    
    </script>

    <!-- Algunos de los estilos de la página de vapers entre ellos el fondo, los textos, colores, fotos... -->

    <style>

    </style>

    <!-- Aquí va la estructura de la visualización de las fotos de los vapers con sus respectivos nombres y precios -->

    <body>

     <h1>LegaGrow Shop</h1>
     <p>Los mejores Vapers de Leganés</p>

     <div class="carousel" data-indicators="true">
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper1"><img src="https://www.vaperss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smok-vape-pen-22-kit-1650-mah-batera-e-cigarrillo-negro-2ml-tpd-cumple-600x600.jpg"></a> 
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper2"><img src="https://i0.wp.com/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB1uFURKFYqK1RjSZLeq6zXppXaM/Msn-M50-calor-electr%C3%B3nico-cigarrillo-Vape-Kit-dispositivo-compatibilidad-para-giratoria-de-palo-de-calor-no.jpg_350x350.jpg"></a> 
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper3"><img src="https://www.elementvape.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/j/o/joyetech_ego_aio_all-in-one_starter_kit_-_black_purple.jpg"></a> 
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper4"><img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1B2xKkN6I8KJjy0Fgq6xXzVXai/80-W-Vape-enorme-de-Vapor-cigarrillo-electr-nico-Vaper-E-Cig-Shisha-pluma-Mech-caja.jpg_640x640.jpg"></a> 
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper5"><img src="https://vaporizadoreschile.cl/1458/voopoo-drag-2-kit-vaper-portatil.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper6"><img src="https://cdn.wallapop.com/images/10420/5a/p4/__/c10420p320299011/i730126877.jpg?pictureSize=W640"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper7"><img src="https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/B1154792601/Mlife-M1-Vape-recargable-encierra-Cig-de-e-con-1500mah.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper8"><img src="https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g5-M01-61-98-rBVaJFlsUm6Ad7jmAAHp3ge6wj8815.jpg/original-mlife-cigar-vape-pens-kits-de-inicio.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper9"><img src="https://image.dhgate.com/albu_342455841_00-1.0x0/high-quality-huge-vapor-e-pipe-electronic.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper10"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_7247.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper11"><img src="https://morethanvapersshop.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_4405-300x300.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="vaper12"><img src="https://cdn.vapo.es/media/catalog/product/cache/4af76433a19704f5fc51241a28dbbf9d/v/a/vaporesso-switcher-220w-kit.jpg"></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="btn green  waves-effect prev duracion-animacion">Anterior</div>
     <div class="btn green  waves-effect next duracion-animacion">Siguiente</div>
```